# How do I add classes produced by a subproject to WEB-INF/classes directory of WAR file in Gradle

Tags: gradle, war, multi-project

I have a multi-project Gradle script.

It should put compiled class files produced by sub-projects into WEB-INF/classes folder.

**UPDATE:**

I tried this code for the war task:

```
war {
        subprojects.each { subproject ->
            project.configurations.compile.dependencies.addAll(subproject.configurations.compile.dependencies)
        }
    
        classpath configurations.compile
}
```

It does not produce any files in classes directory.

How do I do that?

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail? Could you add (parts of) your `build.gradle` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
allprojects {
   jar.enabled = false
}

war {
        def myClasspath = classpath
        subprojects.each { subproject ->
            myClasspath += subproject.sourceSets.main.output
        }
        
        classpath = myClasspath
}
```

It produced class files from sub-projects in WEB-INF/classes directory.